# Why accurcy of CNN using Euclidean distance is 1

Tags: computer-vision

I am a super noob in computer vision and ML. I was watching https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hAeos2TocJ8 video tutorial and the professor said that: **the accuracy of the nearest neighbor classifier on the training data, when using the Euclidean distance** is 0. Can someone please explain why? I really appreciate your help!

Comment: at what time in the video does he say it ?

Answer (score 0):

You have heard it wrong. In the [video at the time 17:10](https://youtu.be/hAeos2TocJ8?t=17m10s). He actually said the accuracy of the nearest neighbor classifier on the training data, when using the Euclidean distance is 100% and not 0. Since training data is used, the image under test is also present in the training set. Hence the minimum euclidean distance between the test image and training data is always 0.